# Moving Data Using Protocol delegates in Navigation controller

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols, segue

I am working on a app where i need to pass data throw a Navigation controller and back.
I got this to work using this tutorial: [link](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/)

In my app i have from my first view controller(in tutorial uiviewcontroller) beside the push segue to secondViewcontroller(in tutorial fooTwoVC) also own to another view controller.

So is my question can i use the same protocol for that VC or do i need to make another protocol?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,FooTwoViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var colorLabel : UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func myVCDidFinish(controller: FooTwoViewController, text: String) {
        colorLabel.text = "The Color is " +  text
        controller.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue"{
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! FooTwoViewController
            vc.colorString = colorLabel.text!
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
import UIKit

protocol FooTwoViewControllerDelegate{
    func myVCDidFinish(controller:FooTwoViewController,text:String)
}

class FooTwoViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate:FooTwoViewControllerDelegate? = nil
    var colorString:String = ""
    @IBOutlet var colorLabel : UILabel!

    @IBAction func saveColor(sender : UIBarButtonItem) {
        if (delegate != nil) {
            delegate!.myVCDidFinish(self, text: colorLabel!.text!)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func colorSelectionButton(sender: UIButton) {
         colorLabel.text = sender.titleLabel!.text!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        colorLabel.text = colorString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some time i finally figured it out and it wasn't that hard after all.
I just needed to change the protocol to:

```
protocol FooTwoViewControllerDelegate{ 
func myVCDidFinish(controller:UIViewController,text:String)
}
```

So i can be used by other view controllers. 
And further i just had the same code in the third view controller.

I you have any question feel free to ask.